# prove linear partial differential operator is continuous for $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ be the test function space (which has LF topology on it.) where $\Omega\subset \Bbb{R}^n$.

Prove partial differential operator defined in classical sense is contiuous (under the LF space):

$$\partial_i:C^\infty_c(\Omega) \to C^\infty_c(\Omega)$$

I don't know how to check it,since the RHS of the above map is also a LF space,this is the key obstacle,for LHS we can convert it to $C^\infty_c(K)$ which is a space generated by seminorm,much easy to deal with.Can we use sequential continuous cireterion here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know for test function space,any linear map from test function space to an locally convex TVS is continuous if and only if it's sequential continuous.

Now if $\phi_i\to 0$ in $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ iff:

$\text{supp}(\phi_i)\subset K$ for some compact $K$.and uniformly convergence of any derivative of any order on this compact set.

Hence $\text{supp}(\partial_j\phi_i) \subset \text{supp}(\phi_i)\subset K$.with derivative of $\partial_j\phi_i$ uniformly convergence on K ,hence the differential operator  $\partial_j$ is continuous.